# Operations on multiple overlapping layers not working

Tags: collision-detection

Hi I am developing a game in android just like Farmville by Zinga. In that game we have to place elements in the diamond shaped field so the don't overlap each other. Now I did coding for placing the field inside the farm field but I cannot stop the problem of overlapping of the farm field. I Am attaching the code that I have down for all this someone please help me....

```
try{
    if(bm1.getPixel((int)initX,(int)initY)!=0){
        if(bm1.getPixel((int)initX,(int)initY+20)!=0){
            if(bm1.getPixel((int)initX-20,(int)initY)!=0){
                if(bm1.getPixel((int)initX+20,(int)initY)!=0){
                    if(bm1.getPixel((int)initX,(int)initY-20)!=0){
                        c.drawBitmap(bm,initX-30,initY-20, paint);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

Comment: All those if statements look horrible.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you're choosing a pixel based collision detection here? A game like Farmville works with a tile-grid. I assume you have such a data-structure in your game that holds all the tiles? Why not simply query this data-structure and look up if a tile is already occupied? If yes, snap the new tile to an adjacent field, or simply prevent the user from dropping a new element there.

**Update**:
Have a look at the following screenshot:

[image: farmville grid]

I drew some lines (white) over it to show you the tile grid. The smallest grid size is probably the size of the small pink rhombus. Of course you can also use bigger tiles, like the 2x2 tile (also colored pink). The Farm-House is a 4x3 tile.

When you place a new element on that grid, you can check if any other tile is already at that position. For a 2x2 tile, you'll only have to check 4 grid cells...

It is of course up to you how coarse your grid should be.

Comment: please can u guide me i am in android game for the  first time

Comment: Another main reason for not using the tiled grid is because if i use tile i can use only that fixed place for the placing of the farm field.Which will not give the look and feel of a good farm game.

Comment: i dont know much about tiled grid if u can help me in this it would be very kind of u...

Comment: @Arun I updated my answer with some more information

Comment: can u help me i dont have any experience

Comment: and i want to know how to place different pocture in that tile is it like 2D array

Comment: means How to get the each tile. Should we consider it as 2D array operation 2. How to fill that tile with images as u may know i have to change images in the tile to show the growth of the plants and all. so plz tel me how to do this .I am alone in this project too

Comment: @Arun: I don't mean to be harsh, but perhaps since you "don't have any experience" you should start with something much smaller and simpler and work your way up.  Programming a game (or anything non-trivial, for that matter) is not something you can just learn in half-an-hour from a forum post.